# Hide filter options with 0 products in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, attributes, filter

I am using Magento 2.3 and need to hide filters in the layered navigation that contain zero products. What files should I modify to complete this?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento product attribute under Storefront Properties, the item needs to be set to Filterable With Results and yes to Use in Search Results Layered Navigation